Calculating functional derivative for a Physics-Informed Neural Network (PINN) using Automatic Differentiation
I'm working with a Physics-Informed Neural Network (PINN) to approximate the solution of a 1D Poisson equation:
$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} = f$
Here, I have an MLP with weight parameters $\theta$ that takes a 1D coordinate $x$ as input and outputs a scalar $u$. Given an equi-spaced grid of $x$ and the corresponding values of $f$, I define the loss function as follows:
$L = \sum_i \left( \frac{d^2u(x_i, \theta)}{dx_i^2} - f_i \right)^2+{\rm (loss\,for\,BC)}$
In the typical PINN formulation, we optimize the network by calculating the gradient of $L$ with respect to $\theta$. However, for a specific application, I need to calculate the functional derivative, $\nabla_u L$.
If I were to compute $\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$ using finite differences, obtaining $\nabla_u L$ would be straightforward. However, for better accuracy, I prefer using automatic differentiation, which seems less straightforward in this context.
Could someone suggest an efficient algorithm or method to calculate $\nabla_u L$ using automatic differentiation?

I think functional differentiation using AD tools is still active research. However, a functional like this has a relatively nice functional derivative that you can find on paper without too much trouble and then implement. Would that be considered an answer to your problem?

Could you let me know the name of the paper?

I'm confused about ' if I were to compute u'' using ... be straightforward' . If you just want to compute u", you have already reached with AD when constructed 'L'

What I meant is, if I calculate u'' using FD, u''~Du, where D is a matrix for FD apporximated 2nd derivative. Then, I can calculate∇u L using AD (actually even don't need AD).
But I calculate u'' using AD here. In this case, I think calculating ∇u L using AD is not straightforward.
